# How to get count people by google plus API

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-api-js-client

The registration I use these scopes

```
var scopes = '://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login ://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me ://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read ://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read';
```

I using this code for get list and count user

```
  var request = gapi.client.plus.people.list({
                    'userId': 'me',
                    'collection': 'visible'
                });
 if (resp.totalItems)
       result.friends = resp.totalItems;
```

result this script is

```
etag:""FT7X6cYw9BSnPtIywEFNNGVVdio/ObDqMibaPxXUs7wb-vH72G2zQbI""
items:[]
kind:"plus#peopleFeed"
title:"Google+ List of Visible People"
totalItems:0
```

where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You have done nothing wrong.  The user in question probably doesn't have anyone else using your application in their circles.

> Acceptable values are:
>   - "connected": The list of visible people in the authenticated user's circles who also use the requesting app. This list is limited to users
>   who made their app activities visible to the authenticated user.
>   - "visible": The list of people who this user has added to one or more circles, **limited to the circles visible to the requesting application**.

Visible is the list of people in the authenticated users circles that are also using your application.

To be clear with the current Google+ API there is no way to get a list back of an authenticated users friends or people they have in circles.  There is no other publicly available API that will return this information.    The only thing you can do is get users that have authenticated the same application and are also connected.  The Google+ API is extremely limited.

Comment: How fix it ? When try use "connected" and "visible" i get nothing. But my acount in th google + have 24 friends. Maybe there are some other ways to get this information.

Comment: Have all of your friends authenticate your application.    There is no other way.  You can only see connections between users using the same application.    The google+ api is very limited.

Comment: I try use Google + Domains that get this information but i get {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}

Comment: Google+ Domains is not the same as Google+ the social media website.  Google+ domains is google for work or classroom and must be paid for and does not give you access to information on Google+ the social media website.

Comment: Then. How get amount or list friends  with Google + ?

Comment: Unless you can get them to all authenticate your application you don't.  Google has not exposed that functionality with the API yet.   What you want to do is not possible with the current Google+ API nor is there another API available to do what you want to do.